# Retrieve multimap values sequentially

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Using the new collections from Google's Guava, i was building a Map and adding values as

```
multimap.put("Date",somestring);
multimap.put("AccountNo",somestring);
multimap.put("Amount",somestring);
multimap.put("Status",somestring);
```

Now while iterating over the map i wanted to retrieve the values in same order as they were put in map like

12-01-2015  909123423133  2000  004

12-02-2015  909123423134  3000  005

12-03-2015  909123423135  4000  006

12-04-2015  909123423136  5000  007

The way i am iterating retrieves all dates first then all account no , then amounts and finally all statuses .

```
Iterator itr= ejLogMap.entries().iterator();
            //System.out.println("Map Size:"+ejLogMap.size());
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry pair= (Map.Entry)itr.next();
                System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
                //itr.remove();
            }
```

Comment: Can you clarify the error/issue you are having?

Comment: I am getting output as

Amount = 10,000.00
Amount = 1,000.00
Amount = 20,000.00

Date = 14/01/15
Date = 14/01/15
Date = 14/01/15

Account_Number = 09990701650014165
Account_Number = 09990801000014165
Account_Number = 09990987600005094

while as i want output like posted above

Comment: please clarify why you need a multimap. java comes with a LinkedHashMap that provides insertion order iterators.

Comment: I am getting output as

Amount = 10,000.00
Amount = 1,000.00
Amount = 20,000.00

Date = 14/01/15
Date = 14/01/15
Date = 14/01/15

Account_Number = 09990701650014165
Account_Number = 09990801000014165
Account_Number = 09990987600005094

while as i want output like posted above

Comment: Actually i wanted to keep track of transactions in a way they were executed .e.g In plain english , say an account number 09990701650014165 was debited by 400 on 12-10-13 with status code 004... i wanted to retrieve output in Table format with Date , Account No, Amount, Status as headers and then fill that Table with its corresponding Values

Comment: have you tried the proposed solutions that actually does output the data the way you asked?

Answer (score 1):

google guava comes with the
`LinkedListMultimap`
where the iteration order corresponds to the insertion order.
I guess you could use that class or just reconsider whether a multimap is really what you want here.

For what you described in the comments I recommend writing a new class containing the information (date, accountNo, ...) and insert instances of this class into an ArrayList, LinkedList, ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your multimap instance is a subclass of `ListMultimap<String, String>` to preserve insertion order **and** you inserted the (date, accountNo, ...) in sequence, then the following should give you the expected output.

```
Iterator<String> dates = ejLogMap.get("Date").iterator();
Iterator<String> accounts = ejLogMap.get("AccountNo").iterator();

while (dates.hasNext() && accounts.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(dates.next() + " " + accounts.net());
}
```

---

**EDIT** triggered by (fully justified) @mueed comment - 
As-is, in your deisgn, the data is organised by *columns* (`"Date"`, `"AccountNo"`,...). You could reorganise it in *rows*, where each item is actually a *tuple* (date, accountNo, amount, status) that can be implemented in a specific POJO class, e.g.

```
public class Transaction {
   String accountNo;
   int amount; 
   Date date;
   int status; // or an enum
   // constructor
   // getters
}
```

Then you can easily process a `List<Transaction>` or even better if transactions are unique a `Set<Transaction>`, sort it on the property you want, filter it, etc. keeping the consistency of each transaction object. If you often need to look up `Transaction` objects on a specific property, you can build a `Map<T, Transaction>` where the key is - for instance - the accountNo. And if you need to preserve the insertion order use a `LinkedHashMap<T, Transaction>`.

Comment: This would still mean misusing multimap. You rely on the insertion order to gather information. If one of the fields is missing at some point, all future information combinations are screwed up.

Comment: Well, it answer OP question. I would certainly not have chosen this design. And the problem you mention is the same for your suggestion.